# SQL: Joining information into a master table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I already played with a lot of SQL statement in my SQL Developer, but don't get it the way I need it.

The task is pretty easy: I have a master table (TAB_MASTER) and want to keep all rows here and just want to add from another table (TAB_REF) information into the master table... where available! I tried it with some RIGHT JOIN ON statements, but the problem was that than the rows with the (nulls) are getting lost (see figure below)... and I want to keep the whole basis from my master table.

```
SELECT ...
FROM TAB_MASTER
RIGHT JOIN TAB_REF ON TAB_REF.KEYREF = TAB_MASTER.KEY
RIGHT JOIN ...
WHERE ...
```

To put it in a nutshell, below a figure of the result I need:

[image: Joining information into master table]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What should the output look like for key `ABC002` - it doesn't seem to have a record in `TAB_REF`?

Comment: Change your join to a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: yes, that's exactly the problem. There is no record  for ABC002 in TAB_REF.

Comment: IN your query RIGHT join means Include all records in ... and only those tat match in tab_ref. and then for all the records included in tab_ref only include those that match in Tab_master.  Change the table join order or use left joins if you want all records from tab_master.  Additionally.  the where clause can ONLY be on the main table elements or the joins become inner joins.  if you have limiting criteria from other tables, INCLUDE it on the table join.

Comment: hm, ok. I thought I have tested it already with LEFT JOIN, but probably not good enough... I will try it tomorrow again :-)

Answer (score 0):

you should join using left join

```
  SELECT TAB_MASTER.*, TAB_REF.*
  FROM TAB_MASTER
  LEFT JOIN TAB_REF ON TAB_REF.KEYREF = TAB_MASTER.KEY
```